# Google SEO Extension URL Trick

Tags: seo

I have recently launched a website & therefore trying to figure out the Seo tricks to make it more visible. I use prerender.io to render javascript.

Can you please tell me how to show extended url results besides the main website link? Is there anything specific i need to do to get the results in the particular format?

For Example : Here main url is Google Voice & rest extended urls.

[image]

Comment: This is generated automatically. You should follow Google recommendations for pages, in particular: give 'em short and clear headers (works better with less then 30 symbols), names and headers H1... Content and internal links are important too. Mainly, my advise is to do everything shorter and clearer.

Answer (score -1):

Well , There is no rules for this structure. Often, my old sites got structured but not the new one.
Google have their own theory for make this structure.